# NuGet error on site build & custom namespaces not seen by the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, umbraco7

I installed Umbraco 7 using NuGet package in my VS (following this tutorial: http://www.systenics.com/blog/setting-up-umbraco-7-in-visual-studio-2013-for-mvc-4-development/).

I now have 2 problems:

1.
Now I'm getting error on every rebuild:

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Directory 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mvcimport\app_data\nugetbackup\20140707-140849\config' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mvcimport\App_Data\NuGetBackup\20140707-140849
```

(line 1 in \Web.config)

The error doesn't occur only on first build after I close the solution and reopen it.

2.
I added my models but the view doesn't see it. Neither controller I added doesn't see my custom namespaces - as you can see on the image MvcImport sees only Controlles namespace which is the one I;m typing in.

Even though (except the case above) the project compiles without error.

[image: This is my controller class]

And when the error (1) occurs on compilation then a number of errors appear also eg.

```
The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcImport' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mvcimport\Controllers\ImportController.cs
```

I can't see how I'm supposed to add my own assemblies if not by simply compiling the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted and recreated the project for the 5th or 6th time now.

Finally it worked (fingers crossed no more problems).

In case someone else needs it I did the following:

1. New project
2. In the New project window selected Installed > Templates > Web > Visual Studio 2012 from the left hand side, .NET Framework 4.5 from the top dropdown and ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application from the project type list then clicked ok
3. On the following screen selected Empty application then clicked OK.
4. Right clicked the project in Solution Explorer, clicked NuGet console, found Umbraco Cms, installed it (you can also install from the package manager console - more here http://www.systenics.com/blog/setting-up-umbraco-7-in-visual-studio-2013-for-mvc-4-development/)
5. Clicked F5 to debug, inserted my cms access details, clicked Customise button at the bottom and added my database connection data.

This tutorial is also helpful http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/install-umbraco-with-nuget.

Important is when you install in the VS2013 instead of Web > ASP.NET Web Application choose Web > Visual Studio 2012 > ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application in point 2 above - this made the difference and allowed me to create the project without errors eventually.